# angularjs template cache lazy loading with permissions

Tags: angularjs

I am not using Angular views or router. simply ng-include . I was able to get lazy loading with `ng-include` (initializing the templates with dummy div) and setting and updating it after getting template from server and updating templateCache.
The problem was most of the time templates where not updated.
Also i want allow user to see the template if the user has permissions. Permissions will be checked on server.

What is the best way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution from the following [link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/wMRtJZ7R480/1OcEXhiLbhsJ)

// CacheTemplate buster.
        //
        // Clears on successful route change (see later) the previous page template
        // from the cache, like that the application DOES SEND another request to
        // the server which in turn has an opportunity to chech access-rights of 
        // the user/session
        $scope.tC = $templateCache;

```
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, next, current) {
        switch( $location.path() ) {
            case '/login' :
                $window.document.title = "LOGIN";
                $scope.loggedIn = false;
                break;
            case '/home' :
                $window.document.title = "HOME";
                $scope.loggedIn = true;
                break;
            default:
                $window.document.title = "";
                $scope.loggedIn = false;
                break;
        };

        // clear cache to trigger reloading
        // (server decides if has permission or not)
        if (current && current.$route) {
            if ($scope.tC.get(current.$route.templateUrl)) {
                $scope.tC.remove(current.$route.templateUrl);
            };
        };
    });
   ...
```